# Как отключить в визуальном редакторе шаблонов в Android Studio автоматическую установку параметров

Tags: android, android-studio, мобильная-разработка

Добрый день. Разрабатываю приложение при помощи Android Studio, опыта верстки под Android еще совсем мало. Потому время от времени приходится прибегать к помощи визуального редактора, но при этом постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что если долго и кропотливо верстать шаблон лэйаута в xml, а потом перейти на вкладку design, то постоянно пересчитываются некоторые параметры. Например,

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
```

превращается в это

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="960dp"
        android:layout_height="497dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
```

И так по всему шаблону. При этом шаблон становится испорченым, и если скомпилировать приложение и установить его на устройство, все перекашивается. Есть ли возможность как-то это отключить? Просто переходить во вкладку дизайн, брать нужный view, а дальше редактировать его в xml, и при этом быть уверенным, что все не перекосилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это `ConstraintLayout` ведет себя так, я так и не смог понять почему такое происходит. Замените родительский `Layout` `ConstraintLayout` на `RelativeLayout` или `LinearLayout` и проблема решена.